# Regex to check validation in Django

Tags: python, django, regex

I am trying to code for the following validation in Django:
"Capital Letters are allowed only as of the first-word letter or only if all letters in a word are uppercase"
I have done this till now, but it is failing, Can someone please help me?

For example:

```
This is The GOOD day - acceptable
ThIS is THE gOOD day - not acceptable
```

My code:

```
RegexValidator(
        regex='(^[A-Z][\sa-z0-9]+$)|(^([A-Z]\w*\s*)+$)',
        message='Capital Letters are allowed only as first word letter or only if all letters in word are uppercase',
        code='invalid_capitalisation'
)
```

Comment: You may probably just check the first char with `^[A-Z]`. Or `^[A-Z][^A-Z]*$` if there can be any chars but uppercase letters after the first uppercase letter.

Comment: Please clarify with some examples what you'd like to match and what you would not. Do you want to match a sentence if every word begins with a capital letter (i.e title case)? Or do you only want the first word first letter to be capital?

Comment: I want to check if a capital alphabet is used in the word then it should be either first character or every character should be capital.

eg: This is The GOOD day - acceptable
       ThIS is THE gOOD day - not acceptable

Comment: @Chase I have updated the  examples

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, I was getting a notification about low rep yesterday, just did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*[a-z][A-Z])(?!.*[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7yCj/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[a-z][A-Z])` - no lowercase letter followed with an uppercase one anywhere in the string is allowed
- `(?!.*[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z])` - no uppercase letter followed with any 1 or more lowercase letters followed with an uppercase one anywhere in the string is allowed
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible